# Troubles with drools class loading

Tags: java, junit, drools, business-rules

I have a problem with my drools but i can't define what exactly problem is so sorry for poor explonations. Here comes my drl file:

```
#created on: 17.05.2012
package ru.abc.one.rules;
import ru.abc.one.entity.application.KBKIForm;

rule "1 risc category" 
    when 
        kbkiForm : KBKIForm
        (
            creditHistoryClassification.contains("Положительная абсолютно") 
|| 
creditHistoryClassification.contains("Положительная существенно") && kup > 0 && kup < 1 
        )  
    then
        kbkiForm.setClientRiskCategory("1");
    end
```

My testing code:

```
    KnowledgeBase kbase = readKnowledgeBase(path);
    StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
    ksession.insert(kbkiForm);
    ksession.fireAllRules();
```

And here comes my error message:

```
2013-03-18 09:10:29,991 ERROR: Rule Compilation error The import ru.abc.one.entity.application cannot be resolved
ru.abc.one.entity.application cannot be resolved to a type [ru.abc.one.rules.RulesServiceTest]
```

P.S. I really need your help guys!

Comment: Solved this problem with adding dialect "mvel" after package declaration

Answer (score 0):

Please include into your class path jar file for the class you are importing or class itself.

ru.abc.one.entity.application.KBKIForm

Drools is unable to find this package so it is throwing this error.

Hoping this helps.

Cheers !!